# Anchor Cycler / Dropdown to import school class data periodically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

SO,

I've been working on some html/javascript/css recently to create an online table for my students to view details, scores and various bits of information but I've hit a brick wall and am unsure how to do what I'm trying to do.

The reason I'm posting all of these in one thread is because several of these I think could conflict and cause the previous edit(s) to fail to function...

**I realise that there are a lot of questions in one here and don't expect someone to code the entire thing, I'm just looking for some help / snippits / ideas and would greatly appreciate especially those with comments/descriptions so that I can continue to learn and improve :)**

---

## Update 13/11/2013 @ 02:43 GMT

#### LATEST: http://jsfiddle.net/pwv7u/

- I'm trying to get `Next Class | Previous Class` to be cycle buttons to move to and from classes the same way the dropdown works.
- The scroll bar what used to be at the bottom of the page has disappeared because of the width has been changed...
- The footer at the bottom doesn't show correctly on mobile devices and the Scroll Left and Scroll buttons don't appear at all on mobile devices.
- The scroll left button is unable to be clicked
- Refreshing the page resets the horizontal scroll position to far left (I'm pretty sure this relates to the scroll bar)
- In regards to the loading/refreshing I guess I'll have to make another post as the current options are nearly there but not quite, I'll example below the way(s) that I ideally want it to work.

  - `main.html` will not contain any class details it would be: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=HwXM67up
  - The "option" (dropdown) would somehow poll a json file to gather a list of classes avaliable
  - The "option" (dropdown) will have options for each individual school class aswell as "All Updating" and "All Non-Updating"
  - Selecting an individual school class will import ONLY that specific school class into the page.
  - Selecting a different individual school class will destory the old school class and import  the newly selected school class.
  - Individual school classes will periodically poll the json file to check for updates / changes to that school classes data and on a change/update it will re-draw/re-import.
  - Selecting "All Updating" will import ALL school classes and periodically poll the json file to check for updates / changes to any school class (if possible only updating the school class what has changed/updated) but with all classes visible on the page.
  - Selecting "All Non-Updating" will do the same as above but won't need to poll the json file to update.
- I can split the data into blocks like: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=MRpjvJp0 (first block example) fairly easily and give them correct titles (titles that would be used in the Option dropdown), unsure how to put them into json format though

Comment: I think it would be wise to put a fixed width on the container and to use `overflow-x:scroll` to handle scrolling in the table

Comment: @Danny It is already in a container and has a scroll bar but I'm trying to get some buttons working correctly, they scroll at the moment but too far (as shown: http://i.imgur.com/4YBHXgs.png)

Comment: Have you considered using "pagination/page-numbers" rather than displaying the entire thing in 1 page? It would make your life easier

Comment: @DennisSylvian I have updated my answer once again, hope I got all of your questions

Comment: I have edited my post once again, Don't forget to look! I have removed your cookie problems.

Comment: @DennisSylvian Another update on answer on me

Comment: also cookies are simple to use,and they are really simple, that is why it is call cookies, simple as a cookie :D

Comment: The edits to this question have weakened the relevancy of some of the answers it received - please try to scope your questions a little more narrowly before asking to avoid this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because, as it now stands, there isn't one specific question that will be of widespread interest to future readers - it's more of a debugging session. Pleased you solved it, though!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update 13/11/2013 @ 12:09 GMT**
Just because you have done an entire edit to your post I just did the same! no need those data!
however I have answered a lot of your questions that you are asking already!
LATEST: http://jsfiddle.net/sijav/pwv7u/1/

- I have done it simply, Just use the blow code: (It's minified!)

  ```
  $("#PreviousClass").click(function(){if(currentClass>1){currentClass--;$('.class-selector').val("CLASS"+currentClass);scrollToAnchor("CLASS"+currentClass);}});
  $("#NextClass").click(function(){if(currentClass<6){currentClass++;$('.class-selector').val("CLASS"+currentClass);scrollToAnchor("CLASS"+currentClass);}});
  ```

Also you need to set Next Class and Previous class ID to the proper one and remove href!

- you need to remove `overflow: auto;` from container class! and then replace $("#container") with `$("body")` in scroll left /right button! so:

  ```
  #container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*overflow: auto;*/
  padding: 80px 0;
  width: 100%;
  }
  ```

  and:

  ```
  $("a.def").click(function () {
          $('body').animate({
              "scrollLeft": "-=204"
          }, 200);
  });

  $("a.abc").click(function () {
      $("body").animate({
              "scrollLeft": "+=204"
          }, 200);
  });
  ```
- It is because you just put that under the footer1! of you bring it to forward it will appear correctly, also why not put a semy transparent black background? `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.58);`
- I'm not seeing any issue on that after that changes mentioned above!
- Good Idea ... let's see...:
- Again I have already give you the code of how to ajax twice! and again you no need to put those in json format! html format will be quite great for what you want to do! just save them as class1.html, class2.html, class3.html, etc. and get the proper html and insert the table instead the current one in container! the code would be:

  ```
  $.ajax({
  url: "class1.html", //this can be anything! better to use a variable like "class"+currentClass
  dataType: "HTML",
  error: function(){alert("Error on communicate to server"}, //what to do on error
  success: function(html){$("#container").html(html)}, //replace the container on success
  });
  ```

Simple right? you can put `http://fiddle.jshell.net/pwv7u/show/` in url to test and see what will happen?!

- why not put those options in a html file and get it like i mention
  above?!
- well, I have told you enough on above,
- the `$("#container").html(SomeHtmlString)` will change the whole container with current one
- you can have ... (wait for it) ... `setInterval(functionThatIncludeAjaxName,milisecond)` (I have told you before)
- you can get all data from them and append what you want with '+' and then `$("container").html(TheAppendedHTMLString)`
- you can have something like this => http://jsfiddle.net/sijav/WJ8Js/
- One thing, for mobile view, you can use some api that scale the whole webpage according to body width! it's very useful on tablet and mobile devices.

Good luck and feel free to ask if you couldn't understands my answer properly or just have a new questions.

Comment: Some awesome answers there, please see my original post (at the bottom) for my reply to your points (it's terribly hard to structure in comments)

Comment: I've added another update for you, between you lovely people replying I'm learning a lot just by looking at your edits and comparing to your previous one.

Comment: I'm still going through everyones contributions cherrypicking the best bits/working bits for me and then I'll update the main post but I can't get your cookies to fully work. The two problems I have at the moment are that the cookies don't delete/erase delete on the next day, they delete/erase after 24 hours (I need to find a way so if the date of the cookie is not the current day then it should delete the cookie) and also when I select a row it adds the cookie but selecting it again I can't edit to remove the cookie (I've never done anything with cookies before other than eat them) :S

Comment: @DennisSylvian the cookie I have made will delete on selecting another row on same class! just look for it, it is shown clearly, as for the next day you mean after 12 PM? it's very simple I just edited my post.

Comment: The cookies are genius, I've still got a few problems though, if you checkout my updated: http://jsfiddle.net/pwv7u/ and then look at my original post you'll see I've updated the comment section.

Comment: I've awarded you your well earned points, I've made a new post about some new bugs that I've made (all css based I think). I must thank you once again for your awesome help. I've learnt a lot of things :) Thanks

Comment: Sorry to come back at you but I'm still having issues incorporating the ajax loading, I can't get it to work at all.

Comment: @DennisSylvian what is your problem with Ajax?! why you can't get it working? if you have opened a post please kindly link it here so I can answer you there.

Comment: I just made my post as I've been trying to get it working and nothing is actually working with ajax and the options that I've tried, I've reverted to a cleaner version without my mess of attempts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136649/autorefreshing-updating-table-using-jquery-ajax-by-either-using-json-or-html-fil

Answer (score 6):

### Preface

In an attempt to cover all of your questions I've tried to include demos in all the answers. Unfortunately I'm only one man and I could not create demos for all the answers.
If anyone feels that hes has something to contribute please feel free to comment or edit this.

### Updates

In response to @DennisSylvian's updated question here are my **updates**.

### Answers

1. 1. To scroll the overflow you would be better off using:

      ```
      $('.table-wrapper')[0].scrollLeft += 50;
      ```

      <kbd>[DEMO here](http://jsbin.com/UxIgIjek/4)</kbd>
   2. If you want to position elements in simple manner using css you can define the parent as `position: relative;` and then give each element a `position: absolute;` to "throw" them out into each corner:

      .controller-wrapper { position: relative; }
      .top-left, .top-right, .bottom-left, .bottom-right { position: absolute; }
      .top-left { top: 0; left: 0; }
      .top-right { top: 0; right: 0; }
      // ...

   **Update**: <kbd>[DEMO here](http://jsbin.com/aVIgiTI/1)</kbd>
2. 1. You can add any offset you have to the scrolling function:

      ```
      var offset = 80; // Or any other calculation
      $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: aTag.offset().top + offset
      }, 1);
      ```
   2. I'm not entirely sure you mean class as in css `.class` or class as in school class but if it's the latter then you can place an id on each `td` you would like to scroll to:

      ```
      <td id="class1" class="scrollto">Title</td>
      <!-- ... -->
      <td id="class2" class="scrollto">Title</td>
      ```

      You can then build your list out of these id's using:

      ```
      var anchorList = [];

      $('.scrollto').each(function(){

        anchorList.push( '<option value="'+ this.id +'">'+ this.id +'</option>' );

      });

      // This is an empty select menu
      $('#anchor-list')
        .append( anchorList.join('') )
        .change(function(){

          scrollToAnchor( $(this).val() );

        });
      ```

      This would require a slight change to your `scrollToAnchor` function:

      ```
      // Put this line
      var aTag = $('#' + aid);

      // Instead of this one:
      var aTag = $("a[id='" + aid + "']");
      ```

      <kbd>[DEMO here](http://jsbin.com/OQehaQU/1)</kbd>
3. This is slightly tricky as the browsers rendering engine does not calculate the columns value based on the contents of the largest cell.

   You would have to either use a plugin (since the code for writing this is much more than this answer can cover), or manually set the width based on the logic of the column data i.e if you have a column that has names in it you can manually set the first `td` width to the longest name in the list.

   **Update**:
   Another option suggested by @sijav is to use:

   ```
   table td { white-space: nowrap; }
   ```
4. **Update**:

   You can pull a single page using a drop down and `$.get()`:

   ```
   <select id="class-list">
     <option value="1">Class 1</option>
   </select>
   ```

   ```
   $('#class-list').change(function(){
     $.get('/server/data/class', { class: $(this).val() }, function(data){
       $('#container').html( data );
     });
   });
   ```

   With the above example your server side code would render the `html` and send in the table ready to be inserted into the dom. Since all the table is being created on the fly you would have to use event bubbling (binding the event to an element that is not rendered from the ajax call).

   Example the highlight row button would have to be written like this:

   ```
    $('#container').on('click', 'tr', function(){
      var $this = $(this);

      $this
        .addClass('highlight')
        .siblings('tr')
        .removeClass('highlight');
    });
   ```

   ---

   The data does not necessarily have to come in `JSON` format (although it would be more agile if at a future point you would need to do something else with the data).

   You can output your data as `HTML` instead of JSON from your server code.

   To check if the data is updated or not you could poll for a flag that your server code should output.

   ```
   // Poll every minute
   setTimeout(function(){

     // Check for changed content
     $.get('/server/data/changed', function( data ){

       // Server indicates content has changed get the content and update
       if ( data.flag ){

         $.get('/server/data/get', function( data ){
           updateHtml( data );
         });

       }

     });
   }, 1000 * 60);
   ```

   The above code is an example of a [polling technique](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery) for updating your content.
5. To "remember" the row that was clicked you can use `localStorage`.

   There are several ways to do this this is one of them:

   ```
    // On page ready
    jQuery(function( $ ){

      var rowIndex = localStorage.getItem('rowIndex');

      if ( rowIndex ) {

        $( 'table tr' ).eq( rowIndex ).addClass('highlight');

      }

      // Save the row to localstorage based on it's index in the table
      var saveRow = function ( index ) {

        localStorage.setItem( 'rowIndex', index );

      };

      // Highlight the row and save it
      $( 'table tr' ).click(function(){

        var $this = $(this);

        $this
          .addClass('highlight')
          .siblings('tr')
          .removeClass('highlight');

        saveRow( $this.index() );

      });

      // On page exit/reload/change check for highlighted row and "save" it to localstorage
      $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){

        saveRow( $('.highlight').index() );

      });

    });
   ```

   <kbd>[DEMO here](http://jsbin.com/uFATOQa/2)</kbd>

Comment: Some very nice answers, please see my original post (at the bottom) for my reply to your points (it's terribly hard to structure in comments)

Comment: I GREATLY appreciate the time, effort and quality of your post, just as I do with the other two people who replied. In an ideal world if stackoverflow had the ability to split the bounty points I would. Your post is not at all irrelevant some things in your post still work, some never worked even at the start. Ultimately the other guys answer for my needs worked better. The revision system means your reply is Still valid to My posts original revision. There are loads of features and methods in this post which will suit people differently. I'm sorry you feel so bitter :( Thanks

Comment: @hitautodestruct When questions have a 250 point bounty on them you often get multiple answers who would be deserving of 'winning' the bounty. There was 3 decent answers to this question all of which probably deserved the bounty. Personally rather bring a complaint to the OP, who was clearly grateful for your answer, you should take it to meta instead and ask for the ability to split bounties to be introduced.

Comment: @DennisSylvian I honestly do not care about the bounty. My point is that there is no relevancy to my answer now that the question has been revised. Saying that someone will take a look at the revision is like saying that someone will look at the revised content of a wikipedia entry, meaning it's not going to happen. If any of my solutions are not working please point them out and I will correct them.
Seems also that the comment you replied to has been deleted, why?

Comment: @hitautodestruct The relevancy is there, my original post was at it's character limit, I had to edit several times to actually edit my main post as for your previous comment someone must of flagged your post and the moderators must of agreed it was "unconstructive, offensive or spam" (hover over the flag button)

Comment: Sometimes SO simply astounds me.. :|

Answer (score 6):

Lets see (*scroll down for update*)

(***demo at*** http://jsfiddle.net/u7UkS/2/)

1. ***Left & Right Table Scrollers (Fixing the overscroll?)***
   You need to animate the `scrollLeft` instead of the `margin`. It will automatically take care of excess values, as it cannot scroll more than allowed..

   ```
   $("a.abc").click(function () {
       $('#container').animate({
           "scrollLeft": "-=204"
       }, 200);
   });

   $("a.def").click(function () {
       $("#container").animate({
           "scrollLeft": "+=204"
       }, 200);
   });
   ```
2. ***Anchor Cycler / Dropdown List to jump to each class?***
   You can loop over the `a` elements, get their `id` and popuplate a `select` element. Then handle the `change` event and animate to the selected position with your `scrollToAnchor` class

   ```
   <select class="class-selector">
       <option value="">-select class-</option>
   </select>
   ```

   and

   ```
   // gather CLASS info
   var selector = $('.class-selector').on('change', function(){
       var id = this.value;
       if (id!==''){
           scrollToAnchor(id);
       }
   });
   $('a[id^="CLASS"]').each(function(){
       var id = this.id,
           option = $('<option>',{
               value: this.id,
               text:this.id
           });
       selector.append(option);
   });
   ```
3. ***Column autosizing?***
   Just set `white-space:nowrap` to the `th`/`td` elements

   ```
   td, th {
       white-space:nowrap;
   }
   ```
4. ***Loading/Updating class sections from JSON.***
   You have not provided any code for this. So i will just describe how to do it..
   For the repeating AJAX request use a timeout and once you handle its result fire a new one

   ```
   function handleData(data){
      //loop over data and edit the DOM
      $.each(data, function(index, item){
        // variable item refers to the current CLASS of the iteration
        // assuming that the JSON is an array of CLASS groups describing the rows..

        //find the DOM section with the current class info and update data..
      });
      setTimeout(checkData, 30000);
   }
   function checkData(){
       $.getJSON('the-url-to-your-json', handleData);
   }
   // initiate the first timeout
   setTimout(checkData, 30000); // 30000 ms is 30sec.
   ```
5. ***Cookies? to remember and restore selected rows***
   No need to use cookies, just in step #4 do not remove the whole row and reinsert, but instead edit the contents of the `td` elements. This way the `tr` will maintain its `class` and the styling will persist. Alternatively, before overwriting the row chack if it has the `selected` class, and if so add it to the row you are about to insert..

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/u7UkS/2/

---

I have also edited your `scrollToAnchor` and removed 80 from the scrollTop to account for the heading

```
function scrollToAnchor(aid) {
    var aTag = $("a[id='" + aid + "']");
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: aTag.offset().top - 80
    }, 1);
}
```

---

---

**Update**

Assuming from your update to the question, that you do not need to show all classes all the time nor update all of them

you could show/hide the CLASSes depending on the selection to the dropdown with this css and code

```
#container tbody, #container thead {
    display:none;
}
#container tbody.current {
    display:table-row-group;
}
#container thead.current {
    display:table-header-group;
}
```

and

```
    var classSelector = $('.class-selector');

    // gather CLASS info
    classSelector.on('change', function () {

        var id = this.value;
        $('#container').find('thead, tbody').removeClass('current');
        if (id !== '') {
            //scrollToAnchor(id);
            var group = $('#' + id).closest('thead');
            group.add(group.next('tbody'))
                .addClass('current');
        }

        // since we changed the current CLASS, initiate a checkdata() so that we can update as soon as possible.. 
        checkData();
    }).trigger('change');
```

Now when we do an AJAX request we can send with it some data to the server to limit the returned info. So in the `checkData` we do

```
function checkData() {
        var currentId = classSelector.val();

        if (currentId !== ''){
            // Start AJAX request
            alert('starting ajax request for ' + currentId);
            // change /echo/json/ with the url to your json
            // delay should be removed, it just for jsfiddle..
            jsonRequest = $.getJSON('/echo/json/', {'delay':2,'class' : currentId}, handleData);        
        }
    }
```

and `handleData`

```
function handleData(data) {
    alert('handling data');
    //loop over data and edit the DOM        
    var classBody = $('#container').find('tbody.current');
    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
        // variable item refers to the current CLASS of the iteration
        // assuming that the JSON is an array of CLASS groups describing the rows..

        // populate classBody with the JSON data

    });
    jsonTimeout = setTimeout(checkData, 10000); // change the 10000 to whatever you want.. i set it to 10 seconds to see the repeating..
}
```

You will notice the `jsonTimeout  = setTimeout(..)`  and `jsonRequest = $.getJSON(..)`. 
We store those in variable so we can abort them when we change the current CLASS to avoid excess processing

This is done by adding

```
    if (jsonTimeout) clearTimeout(jsonTimeout);
    if (jsonRequest) jsonRequest.abort();
```

to the `change` handler of the dropdown.

**Updated Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/u7UkS/4/

Comment: Please see my updated original post, I've added some comments in there at the bottom as It's impossible to structure replies in comments >_< 
Thank you ever so much :)

Comment: @DennisSylvian i have updated my answer (*updated part is at the end of the answer*)

Comment: I've added another update for you, I must say though your code is really impressive I'm learning loads of little things :P

Answer (score 3):

1) You have to realize that you're not scrolling the page like you would do that with your scroll on a mouse. You're actually manipulating margin-left and this behaviour causes that you give it very large values. Then, it looks like you have told. There's a huge space between table and end of your screen. To solve it, you have to add an if statement that is going to check if you're trying to increase margin-left too much.

```
 $("a.def").click(function() {
    $("#gradient-style").each(function(){
        var margin =$(this).css("margin-left");

        if(margin > -204)
             $(this).animate({"margin-left":"+=204px"},200);
        else
             $(this).animate({"margin-left":"+=" +(-margin)},200);
    });
});
```

5) You could use **localStorage** variable which is built-in JavaScript feature. You can simply define any variable and use it over session. Here's example:

```
 localStorage.numberOfRow =1;
 console.log(localStorage.numberOfRow);     //1
```

Comment: I've tried your example for the first option but I'm still unable to get it to work, for some reason it doesn't scroll at all when I try adding an if statement check. As for your reply to point 5, I never knew "localStorage" existed and it looks pretty awesome but I spent a fair few hours yesterday getting nowhere with it.

Comment: It worked on very first copy of your code. Now you changed it to ScrollLeft and it's a better idea.
About localStorage, it should work over your website, but maybe there is some issue due to browsers support. You should try to read reference.