# Updating the server-side json to output filtered table data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Is it possible to update the server-side JSON file using AJAX in bootstrap-table?

data-url="scripts/users.php"

I am using a PHP file to echo the output of the sql queries to the table.
First Name | Last Name | Category | Group

This works well, but I want to add 4 select tags each to filter a column. I have replicated the server-side JSON within users.php but this time it will echo the filtered rows to the JSON.

Can this be done? How can I switch to the filtered JSON?

NOTE: all this logic is within users.php (aside from the AJAX of course).

```js
if (!empty($_POST['first_name'])) {
  //code to create and return filtered JSON
} else if (!empty($_POST['last_name'])) {
  //code to create and return filtered JSON
} else if (!empty($_POST['category'])) {
  //code to create and return filtered JSON
} else if (!empty($_POST['group'])) {
  //code to create and return filtered JSON
} else {
  //code to create and return unfiltered JSON
  /*THIS ALWAYS EXECUTES ONLOAD, BUT **I WANT IT TO GIVE WAY FOR THE FILTERED JSON  AND ONLY REACTIVATE ONLOAD OR IF ALL FILTERS ARE REMOVED***/
}
```

**UPDATE:**
In my users.php code I have successfully been able to run each filtered query individually (depending on what is selected). When the page first loads the table is empty but present. Users must select at least one option for the table to output any data.

I am having issues letting the table (written in the .html page) know to switch to the filtered results while the filter is active.

Here is the code that resides in each of the if/else conditions:

```js
$limit = $_GET['limit'];
$offset = $_GET['offset'];
fname = $_POST['first_name'];

if (!empty($_POST['first_name'])) { //filter by the selected name

  //get TOTAL rows for PAGINATION
  $stmt_TOTAL_ROWS = "SELECT first_name, last_name, category, group 
            . "\
  n "
            . "
  FROM users
    .
  "\n"
  .
  "WHERE first_name ='$fname'";
  $result_TOTAL_ROWS = mysqli_query($mysqli, $stmt_TOTAL_ROWS);
  $num_rows_TOTAL_ROWS = mysqli_num_rows($result_TOTAL_ROWS);

  $stmt = "SELECT first_name, last_name, category, group 
            . "\
  n "
            . "
  FROM users
    .
  "\n"
  .
  "WHERE first_name ='$fname' ORDER BY first_name LIMIT $offset, $limit";
  $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $stmt);

  $cart = array();
  $i = 0; //index the entries


  if ($num_rows_TOTAL_ROWS > 0) { //if table is populated...

    // enter data of each row
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

      $cart[$i] = array(
        "First Name" => htmlspecialchars($row['first_name']),
        "Last Name" => htmlspecialchars($row['last_name']),
        "Category" => htmlspecialchars($row['category']),
        "Group" => htmlspecialchars($row['group']),

      );

      $i = $i + 1; //add next row
    }

    //encoding the PHP array
    $json_server_pagination_data = array(
      "total" => intval($num_rows_TOTAL_ROWS), // total rows in data
      "rows" => $cart, //data
    );

    echo json_encode($json_server_pagination_data); // allow table to access the data
  } else {
    //do nothing . no data in sql query
  }
}
```

Comment: you may want to look into filtering the results using javascript rather than server side, that way when the filters are turned back off you dont have to make another call

Comment: Na, it's fine to filter it serverside, otherwise you have to transmit all of the data every time. You'll probably end up doing something like, http://stackoverflow.com/a/20172816/1318813 that goes into way more detail then you probably need though. The gist is that you make the request, get the updated data, then update the table using the results from the ajax request.

Comment: Though if it's not so much data that you can load it all at once, sorting with javascript with a library like tablesorter.com is going to be faster to implement.

Comment: The tables will contain large amounts of data and this table data will be getting updated regularly (users can view updates without page reloads via refresh button) . It must be server-side.