# Javascript variable not updating from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can I get a variable in my javascript function to update every time the script is ran? The variable grabs a PHP string, which it then seems it stores it and doesn't update the value ever till a page refresh is done.

**SCRIPT:**

```
setInterval(function () {
        var options = {
            useEasing : true, 
            useGrouping : true, 
            separator : ',', 
            decimal : '.', 
        };
        var value123 = <?php echo $amount22; ?>;
        var value234 = <?php echo $unpaidbtc; ?>;
        var demo = new CountUp("counter", value123, value234, 10, 1, options);
        demo.start();
      }, 5000);
```

Basically it grabs the `$unpaidbtc` value for my php in the page. This script will run every 5 seconds, but instead of updating with the new value the php has, it uses the first value it grabbed and never updates to the new PHP string.

Is there anyway to make the script update and re grab the PHP script from the page automatically?

Example: `$unpaidbtc` = 10 on start and `$unpaidbtc` = 15 after 5 seconds, but counter only goes up to 10. How can it grab the new value without refreshing the page and stuff, thanks!

Comment: you have to use ajax.

Comment: @DanielA.White How would I go around converting this to work with Ajax? Never have worked with that.

Comment: "Never have worked with that" --- now as you have a keyword, spend few minutes and make a research.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: [**This answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20172816/2341603) from another question provides a fairly comprehensive guide to AJAX. There's also the [**official AJAX documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Keep in mind that AJAX requires jQuery. You can use [**XMLHttpRequest**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) as a raw JavaScript alternative :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge - That example requires jQuery, though. If it's not already included in the OP's project, there's no need to include it just to make a simple Ajax call. It's literally 8 rows of code if you go with native js...

Comment: Ajax I don't see would help as the PHP string is a output of a mysql query through php, so the value isn't stored locally nor can it be queried through a separate php file.

Comment: Even though it sounds trivial - updating a counter - it's not. You have to determine **where** you want to save this counter. You can save this counter in a cookie/local storage, or you can save this on your server (with a file or database). Saving the counter on the client's computer means when you move to another computer the counter is different. If you save the counter on the server, everyone will see the same counter - but they will also all be able to modify the counter. You could also have different counters for different users. **You should probably give us more info about this.**

Comment: @DaveChen The php string is being grabbed from a mysql database, then the value is saved as a string through php and parsed through js how I showed. The counter is in the middle of the body. The values being displayed in the counter are stored/grabbed from the mysql database.

Comment: So when multiple people visit this page, what should happen? In the case of only one person viewing the page, `unpaidbtc` will increase by an example of 100 units every 5 seconds let's say. If two people are on the website, would `unpaidbtc` increase by 200 units ever 5 seconds?

Comment: @ObsidianAge The statement _"Keep in mind that AJAX requires jQuery"_ is plain wrong! Ajax does _not_ require jQuery. jQuery is just a library that has a simplified wrapper for it. That's all..

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes, but the data being called is data that needs to be secured. I see using a separate php file it could cause a major security hole, if not done right.

Comment: "I see using a separate php file it could cause a major security hole, if not done right" --- this statement is plain wrong.

Comment: Security hole? In what way? You're _fetching_ data. You're not _posting_ anything sensitive at all (even then, it wouldn't be more of a security hole than an ordinary form post)

Comment: @DaveChen Every user has their own `unpaidbtc` and like you said if they sit on the page it will add "100" to `unpaidbtc` every 5 seconds. Every user has a unique `id` and `unpaidbtc` that are all going up with or without the use on the page, the js is just used to update the displayed values. I had it where it would update the `unpaidbtc` every 5 seconds, just without animation. I need the animation part.

Comment: It really goes to nowhere. @TymeBomb the thing is: 1. If you need to update the value from the server without page refresh - you need ajax. 2. For ajax you better have the data in a way that is easy to consume. 3. There is no item #3. 4. I highly recommend you to ask someone experienced codereview whatever you implement: if you really deal with bitcoins, chances are your script has a lot of various security holes.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Well I would need to pass data through the request "?id=3845", unless I throw it in the cookies, but like I said not worth it, and it should be able to be done from 1 whole page.

Comment: @zerkms I currently use this script to refresh the part of the page every 5 seconds: `$( document ).ready(function() {
      var $scores = $("#time");
      setInterval(function () {
          $scores.load("index.php #time");
      }, 5000);
    });` Is this Ajax or just javascript? as it refreshes the part of the page without refreshing the whole page.

Comment: How do you get that "secret" ID in the first place? Why is it even a secret? You simply _can't_ update the page without reload without making a new request (using Ajax).

Comment: Good. What is your problem then?

Comment: @zerkms It doesn't animate the count up on the counter when it refreshes the values, that is the problem I am having. All it does it refresh the values with no animation at the moment.

Comment: There is no even a single mention of "animation" in the question. Could you update the question so that it addressed the **real problem**?

Comment: @zerkms The script in my post is for the animation, but it is grabbing the PHP string from a above php function only once, not everytime it runs 5 seconds... just grabs it on page load.

Comment: `$.load()` is actually using Ajax to load the content.

Comment: I honestly tried, but I cannot understand what your *current problem* is. Update your question so that it was clear to everybody not familiar with your codebase and your project.

Comment: @zerkms The script already works and animated every 5 seconds, just the PHP string it gets its new value from is the same because it doesn't regrab the new value from the PHP

Comment: @TymeBomb you have not provided the corresponding php code that generates responses for your ajax requests.

Comment: You need to take a step back and read all the comments. Then delete this question, write a new question with the _actual_ issue explained in _detail_ and show _all_ the _relevant_ code together with what you _expect_ to get and what you _actually_ get. Right now, your question is all over the place. You're moving the goal post in every other comment.

Comment: Understood, I have no idea how to explain it the right way, it's not easy to explain this issue, thanks for the help I got so far.

Comment: If you don't know how to explain it, there's _no chance at all_ for us to understand it...

Comment: "it's not easy to explain this issue" --- it's a trivial problem as soon as you decompose it to smaller parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments I think I understand what you want:

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

function getValues(callback) {
    ajax.abort();

    ajax.open("GET", "index.php?showme=1", true);
    ajax.send();

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200)
            callback(JSON.parse(ajax.responseText));
    };
}

setInterval(function() {
    var options = {
        useEasing: true,
          useGrouping: true,
          separator: ',',
          decimal: '.',
    };

    getValues(function(obj) {
        var value123 = obj.amount22;
        var value234 = obj.unpaidbtc;
        var demo = new CountUp("counter", value123, value234, 10, 1, options);
        demo.start();
    });

}, 5000);
```

You can get away with only using one PHP page, let's assume it's called `index.php`:

```
<?php

//do your database calls to get $amount22 and $unpaidbtc

if (isset($_GET['showme'])) {

    echo json_encode(array(
        'amount22'  => $amount22,
        'unpaidbtc' => $unpaidbtc
    ));
    exit;
}

//the rest of your page (with the html/javascript)
```

Note that if your page is not called `index.php`, you need to change this line:

```
ajax.open("GET", "index.php?showme=1", true);
```

Comment: This is what I want, but is there anyway to convert the php string to json from the same file and read it from that file too instead of using that external php file? Could I use # for it?

Comment: Yup, you can put everything into one page. I've edited to show how.

Comment: The `#` sign, if I'm understanding correctly, is used only for client sided navigation, i.e `page.php#hello` - PHP can't read this value. I've used `index.php?showme=1` to only show the values in JSON.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort, I have found a way to work this how I needed!